# am trying to include a page in a div after i click a link but its not working

Tags: php, html, css

```
 **students.php page**   
     <?php 
        include('includes/studentsheader.php');
        include('includes/studentsmain.php');
        include('includes/getfooter.php');
        ?>  


    *studentsmain.php page*
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="studentslist">
        <li><a href="students.php?addstudents.php">Add Student</a></li>
        <li><a href="students.php?ViewStudent.php">View Student</a></li>
        <li><a href="students.php?UpdateStudent.php">Update Student</a></li>
        <li><a href="students.php?DeleteStudent.php">Delete Student</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
        <?php 

        if(isset($_GET['addstudents.php'])) 
        { 
        include('includes/addstudents.php'); 
        } 
        else if(isset($_GET['ViewStudent.php']))    {include('includes/ViewStudent.php');}
        else if(isset($_GET['UpdateStudent.php'])){include('includes/UpdateStudent.php');}
        else if(isset($_GET['DeleteStudent.php'])){include('includes/DeleteStudent.php');}
        ?>
        </div>

        </div>
        </div>

    *addstudents.php page*

    <div class="">
        <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
        <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
        </label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

am trying to include a page in a div after i click a link but its not working want to include addstudents.php div in col-md-9 div when i click a add students link. students.php is placed outside the includes folder the other folder are placed inside includes folder. when  i click addstudents link nothing happens at all

Comment: Go read up on the basics of how GET parameters work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually get method is replacing `.`  to `_` . so try below code:

```
if(isset($_GET['addstudents_php'])) 
{ 
    include('includes/addstudents.php'); 
}
```

Comment: yeah its working thanks Ahmed <div class="col-md-9">
<?php 

          if(isset($_GET['addstudents_php'])) 
           { 
            include('includes/addstudents.php'); 
      } 
      else if(isset($_GET['ViewStudent_php'])){include('includes/ViewStudent.php');}
      else if(isset($_GET['UpdateStudent_php'])){include('includes/UpdateStudent.php');}
      else if(isset($_GET['DeleteStudent_php'])){include('includes/DeleteStudent.php');}
 ?>
  </div>

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you so that it will help others in future also :)